# get the selected text with window.getSelection() in ionic angular

Tags: ionic-framework, text, textarea, getselection

How should I implement the `window.getSelection().toString();` in an ionic app? I tried to get the plain text of the selected text from ionic textarea but I don't know how my app will be able to listen to that event.

At first, I'm trying to use the `press` gesture and get the selected text. But then it's not the correct way to do as when I move the app cursor selector to another text to select more text, my app no longer be able to listen to that selection event.